# Does Composite Cronjob execute all jobs in sequence if one job fails

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

when we create a Composite Cronjob with 4 cronjobs and 3rd job(cronjob entry) is failed to execute, will the 4th job in sequence execute?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in such situations is to check the behavior of a composite cronjob. We can find this within the associated job, `CompositeJobPerformable`, and, we can see that the job is iterating through the composite entries, and in case one of these throws an exception, the rest of the composite entries won't be executed.